# Is there a stable way to set echarts axis limits from html id value

Tags: javascript, html, heatmap, echarts

I'm writing an electron.js app where I'm using echart.js to display a heatmap.
Two html input tags are used to let the user set the axis limits for the heatmap.

```
    <span>
      <input type="number" id="min_limit" value= 1>
      <input type="number" id="max_limit" value= 2> 
    </span>
```

In the javascript code I'm simply using the following to get this content:

```
    data_min = document.getElementById('min_limit').value;
    data_max = document.getElementById('max_limit').value;
```

The problem occurs when I try to use these two variables within the echart option:

```
option = {
       ...
       visualMap: {
             min: data_min,
             max: data_max,
             ...
             }
         }
```

I get the following error:
"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'addColorStop' on 'CanvasGradient': The value provided ('undefined') could not be parsed as a color."

The interesting thing is that the program works when I try any of the following (only one of the input values respectively but not both at the same time):

```
option = {
       ...
       visualMap: {
             min: 0,
             max: data_max,
             ... // No errors
             }
         }

option = {
       ...
       visualMap: {
             min: data_min,
             max: 1,
             ... // No errors
             }
         }

option = {
       ...
       visualMap: {
             min: 0,
             max: 1,
             ... // No errors
             }
         }
```

And calling*:

```
myChart.setOption(option);
```

To display the chart.

Any suggestions? I'm new to html and JavaScript so there may be an obvious error that I'm missing.

*EDIT: Forgot to mention that I'm using "setOption" to change the appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set echarts option directly. Need to use `setOption` for add data, [see documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption).

**Update**

Your implementation does not work because Echarts not understand what need do with inputs. Getting value you in fact calling the getter (special built-in function) of input component. The Echarts does't know how to call getter, it's expecting just value.

With regard to the implementation I would have the following way.

1. Define function that read value for inputs.
2. Define function that update Echart's min/max.
3. Attach event listener to body element for listen inputs change event.

And then after receive the event call the update Echarts.

```js
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

 var hours = ['12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
        '7a', '8a', '9a','10a','11a',
        '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
        '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'];
 var days = ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
        'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'];

  var data = [[0,0,5],[0,1,1],[0,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,4,0],[0,5,0],[0,6,0],[0,7,0],[0,8,0],[0,9,0],[0,10,0],[0,11,2],[0,12,4],[0,13,1],[0,14,1],[0,15,3],[0,16,4],[0,17,6],[0,18,4],[0,19,4],[0,20,3],[0,21,3],[0,22,2],[0,23,5],[1,0,7],[1,1,0],[1,2,0],[1,3,0],[1,4,0],[1,5,0],[1,6,0],[1,7,0],[1,8,0],[1,9,0],[1,10,5],[1,11,2],[1,12,2],[1,13,6],[1,14,9],[1,15,11],[1,16,6],[1,17,7],[1,18,8],[1,19,12],[1,20,5],[1,21,5],[1,22,7],[1,23,2],[2,0,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,0],[2,3,0],[2,4,0],[2,5,0],[2,6,0],[2,7,0],[2,8,0],[2,9,0],[2,10,3],[2,11,2],[2,12,1],[2,13,9],[2,14,8],[2,15,10],[2,16,6],[2,17,5],[2,18,5],[2,19,5],[2,20,7],[2,21,4],[2,22,2],[2,23,4],[3,0,7],[3,1,3],[3,2,0],[3,3,0],[3,4,0],[3,5,0],[3,6,0],[3,7,0],[3,8,1],[3,9,0],[3,10,5],[3,11,4],[3,12,7],[3,13,14],[3,14,13],[3,15,12],[3,16,9],[3,17,5],[3,18,5],[3,19,10],[3,20,6],[3,21,4],[3,22,4],[3,23,1],[4,0,1],[4,1,3],[4,2,0],[4,3,0],[4,4,0],[4,5,1],[4,6,0],[4,7,0],[4,8,0],[4,9,2],[4,10,4],[4,11,4],[4,12,2],[4,13,4],[4,14,4],[4,15,14],[4,16,12],[4,17,1],[4,18,8],[4,19,5],[4,20,3],[4,21,7],[4,22,3],[4,23,0],[5,0,2],[5,1,1],[5,2,0],[5,3,3],[5,4,0],[5,5,0],[5,6,0],[5,7,0],[5,8,2],[5,9,0],[5,10,4],[5,11,1],[5,12,5],[5,13,10],[5,14,5],[5,15,7],[5,16,11],[5,17,6],[5,18,0],[5,19,5],[5,20,3],[5,21,4],[5,22,2],[5,23,0],[6,0,1],[6,1,0],[6,2,0],[6,3,0],[6,4,0],[6,5,0],[6,6,0],[6,7,0],[6,8,0],[6,9,0],[6,10,1],[6,11,0],[6,12,2],[6,13,1],[6,14,3],[6,15,4],[6,16,0],[6,17,0],[6,18,0],[6,19,0],[6,20,1],[6,21,2],[6,22,2],[6,23,6]];

data = data.map(function (item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'];
});

option = {
    tooltip: {
        position: 'top'
    },
    animation: false,
    grid: {
        height: '50%',
        top: '10%'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: hours,
        splitArea: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: days,
        splitArea: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    visualMap: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        calculable: true,
        orient: 'horizontal',
        left: 'center',
        bottom: '15%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Punch Card',
        type: 'heatmap',
        data: data,
        label: {
            show: true
        },
        emphasis: {
            itemStyle: {
                shadowBlur: 10,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
            }
        }
    }]
};

  function updateChart(values){
    myChart.setOption({ visualMap: values })
  };

 document.body.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    var targets = document.querySelectorAll('.changeable');
    var new_values = [...targets].map(target => {
      var key_name = target.id.split('_')[0];
      return { [key_name]: target.value };
    });
    var new_values = Object.assign(new_values[0], new_values[1]);
     updateChart(new_values);
 });

  myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
 <span>
  <input type="number" class="changeable" id="min_limit" value= 1>
  <input type="number" class="changeable" id="max_limit" value= 5> 
</span>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I use "setOption" - I updated the question to adress this. Have you used inputs for chaging axis limits? Are there any better way of asking the user to change axis limits?

Comment: May be not `Axis`, may be `visualMap`? I do not understand why you change min/max in this way and why you not like standard limits but is possible and relates more to JavaScript then to Echarts. I will update answer.

Comment: Thank you Sergey! Your code works, but I needed to add a "parseFloat()" when returning the "key_name". I would like to have a chart where the user can change the axis limits instead of having hardcoded default limits. Your solution allows just that. Thank you.

Comment: Great! I am glad that this solution suits you.